# fn:length is undefined on all my pages now, jstl

Tags: jstl

For some reason I am getting the error below now when I do a maven install in the target folder.  Why would this error happen?

The function fn:length is undefined

```
${fn:length(model.action.websites) <= 0}

<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.  After two hours of cleaning, compiling, mvn cleaning and installing it finally broke through.  I am so glad I am a .NET developer.

Comment: If we go down this route, I'm glad I don't use Maven (in other words: don't generalize too much).

Comment: a little bit more information on this topic would be helpful for others.